# display error message if user already exist

Tags: php, mysqli

How i can setup function to display `error message` if the user already exist on `database` ?

Help me please to understand this concept !

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['message'] = '';

$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'accounts');

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    $username = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['username']);

    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username)" . "VALUES ('$username')";

    // if the query is successful, redirect to play page
    if ($mysqli->query($sql) === true) {
        header("location: play.php");
    } else {
        $_SESSION['message'] = "Username exist";
        header("location: index.php");
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: It seems like you're almost there - but see about sql injection

Answer (score 0):

Your code may not work if you didn't add `unique` index for username column in your MySQL table.

if you don't want to edit Mysql database, you should check if the username exists before you insert it into the database.

in your code, you're relying on MySQL server to throw an error which is the best way to find duplicates.

To make username column unique run the following query:

> CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uname_uniq ON tablename (username);

Comment: i have 2 columns on database, 
1- id Primary int(13) 
2-  username varchar(13)

Answer (score 0):

Function to check if username already exists:

```
function username_exists($username){
    global $mysqli;
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM users WHERE username = ?;");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    return (isset($row['total']) AND $row['total'] > 0); // returns true if username exists and false otherwise..
}
```

With it...

**You can do:**

```
if(username_exists($username) === true){
    echo "Username: $username already exists!";
}
else {
    // insert user record to database
}
```